# Overlaying content AppBarLayout using new Material Design

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, android-toolbar, android-coordinatorlayout

### i want to achieve something like that. (not the FAB or the Snackbar). How can i create a layout, overlaying the AppBarLayout? Like this! V

[image: AppBarLayout with overlaying content]

**Like the Play Store! V**

[image: Just like on the Play Store V]

**My AppBarLayout with CoordinatorLayout and NestedScrollView with RelativeLayout as content looks like this!  V**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/rootLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/_118sdp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:contentScrim="@color/mpc_pink"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="@dimen/_40sdp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <de.mypostcardstore.widgets.ItemImageView
            android:id="@+id/header"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@color/mpc_pink"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.7" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/article_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:contentScrim="@color/mpc_pink"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />


    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="?android:colorBackground"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent".....>
```

**It would be awesome if someone could help me out. I can not find ANYthing on the internet..
Thank you in advance!**

Answer (score -1):

not difficult, some pseudo XML for you

```
<FrameLayout>

    // this is the background part
    <LinearLayout>
       <Top part "blue">
       <Bottom part "white">
    <LinearLayout/>

    // here is your main content that overlay the background
    <MainContent margingTop="toolbar_height + something more"/>

    // here is the toolbar with no background
    <ToolBar background=@null height="toolbar_height"/>
<FrameLayout/>
```

Comment: Thanks, but i want to achieve this with the new material Design, as shown on the screenshots.. you use CoordinatorLayout instead of Framelayout now.

Comment: I showed how to achieve the overlaying of the elements as per screenshots, the colors and shades is just properly add backgrounds. The "main content" should be a `CardView` etc.

Comment: Not very helpful at all and doesn't answer the OP's questions.